# Counting amount of friends and displaying as a number PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been creating a social networking site and have a friends system in place where the users can add/remove each other and it displays the users friends and profile pictures. All i need now is just to retrieve a total number of friends rather than the friends being listed individually for example (Sam has 21 friends). My 'friends' table looks like this.

```
    id   user_one   user_two
     4          3         9
     5          3         7
     6         11         3
```

I have tried to run a query:

```
        $friend_count = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE
        ($user_one = '$id' AND $user_two = '$id')";
```

But i am not sure how to then display the number or if this is even along the right lines.

I am fairly new to PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your query appears to check that both users are the same user. Even if users can be friends with themselves, I doubt this is intended.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am working on the assumption that i should be counting the amount of the same id to the user. Example $id = 3 so count how many times 3 appears in the table to give me my total number of friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query should be:

```
$friend_count = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE
        ($user_one = '$id' OR $user_two = '$id')");
```

you should use mysqli because mysql is deprecated, so you can do like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT count(*) as count_friends FROM friends WHERE
            ($user_one = '$id' OR $user_two = '$id')");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$count_friends = $row['count_friends'];
```

Comment: You sir are a genius! worked perfectly...Should i be changing the rest of my php syntax to 'mysql' ?

Comment: mysqli not mysql, because it doesn't exist in new PHP versions

Comment: It autocorrected for me...Great i shall change my existing code. Thanks again for your help. i have been trying for hours to get that working!!

Answer (score 0):

See what you're doing is this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE ($user_one = '$id' AND $user_two = '$id')
```

It is looking in friends for rows where user_one AND user_two (which should not be variables... or between brackets) are the same.

So for something to be counted:
user_one must be user_two

I imagine your intention is two check whether $id is either found in user_one or user_two throughout the table.

Meaning you need OR and not AND

Corrected Select statement:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$id' OR user_two = '$id'
```

UPDATE - Should do what you need:

```
$select= "SELECT count(*) FROM friends WHERE user_one = '$id' OR user_two = '$id'";
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER", "PASSWORD", "test");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo reset($row);
```

Comment: Yes that is my intention and thank you for the help. how do i then echo that as a number?